# What do Google Chrome Scope Variables really mean?

Tags: tinymce, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying out Google Chrome's dev tools, which is showing some strange values.
On the picture you can see the value of *obj* set to "k.create.Editor" (marked in red).

My question is, how do we find this value in JavaScript code?
I have tried *alert(obj)*, but all I get is *[object Object]*.
*typeof obj* returns *Object*. So where is this *k.create.Editor* coming from? How do I compare *obj* with the value "k.create.Editor"?

(To give a little more detail, I am working with TinyMCE, but this should not be relevant)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the name of the class.
DevTools is able to infer the class name of an object with help of V8 api.

Comment: I'm guessing it is not possible to get this class name in JS code?